# How to get properly typed cv::Mat_<_Tp>.data as _Tp*?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv-mat

In my template functions I have instances of `cv::Mat_<T>`. My problem is that `cv::Mat_<T>.data` does not return `T*`, but `uchar*`.

Is it safe to cast `cv::Mat_<T>.data` to `T*` using a `reinterpret_cast<T*>`?

One example would be this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
cv::Mat_<T> AddAxis(cv::Mat_<T> const &tensor) {
    const int kTensorOrder = tensor.size.dims();
    const int kNewTensorOrder = kTensorOrder+1;
    int new_tensor_size[kNewTensorOrder];
    new_tensor_size[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < kTensorOrder; i++) {
        new_tensor_size[i+1] = tensor.size[i];
    }
    cv::Mat_<T> new_tensor = cv::Mat_<T>(kNewTensorOrder, new_tensor_size, tensor.data);  // A
    cv::Mat_<T> new_tensor = cv::Mat_<T>(kNewTensorOrder, new_tensor_size, reinterpret_cast<T*>(tensor.data));  // B
    cv::Mat_<T> new_tensor = cv::Mat_<T>(kNewTensorOrder, new_tensor_size, const_cast<T*>(tensor.template ptr<T>(0)));  // C

    return new_tensor;
}
```

Line A fails compilation with the message

> error: no matching function for call to 'cv::Mat_::Mat_(const int&, int [kNewTensorOrder], uchar* const&)'

Line B compiles fine, but is it safe, though, even when `tensor.isContinuous()` is `false`?

Line C also compiles fine. Should I use this one?

Comment: If `tensor.isContinous` is false due to padding, you can pass the actual stride/step in the `cv::Mat_` constructor.